# is there a way to cover a flash with a div when wmode is 'gpu'?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash, parameters, wmode

i know this can be done by changing wmode to "transparent or opaque". But is there any way to show the div over the flash file using wmode "gpu" ..

Answer (score 0):

No you can only do this with opaque or transparent modes. In these modes, the browser is responsible for rendering and can control z-ordering with respect to other objects under its control.

With all the other wmodes, it's up to the flash player to draw directly to the screen, which will be on top of all other content.